# Django NoReverseMatch at /school/new-school/

Tags: python, django, url, reverse, lazy-evaluation

What is wrong with my approach?

When I post new data, I want it to return back to the page with the input fileds empty. But it gives me this error

> ```
> NoReverseMatch at /school/new-school/
> ```
>
> Reverse for 'new-school' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

This is my model. Please note, reverse_lazy was imported

```
class SchoolList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('new-school')
```

This is my url.py

```
url(r'^school-list/$', SchoolListtView.as_view(), name='school-list'),   
url(r'^new-school/$', CreateSchoolListView.as_view(), name='new-school'),       
url(r'^school(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', SchoolListUpdate.as_view(), name='update-school')
```

This is my view for create.

```
class CreateSchoolListView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'school\create_form.html'
    model = SchoolList
    fields = ['name']
```

This is how I specified the urls in the template.

```
<a href="{% url 'school:new-school' %}">Create New School</a>
<a href="{% url 'school:school-list' %}">View all Schools</a>
```

When the page is displayed, I can click the links and it will go to the correct pages. But when I post a data, the it throws the above error. I have been on this for hours and read many of the answers online. It seems mine is a unique case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding namespace to get_absolute_url().

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('school:new-school')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import your app's urls in your project's urls with namespace like:

```
url(r'^school/', include('school.urls', namespace="school"))
```

to use namespace in your templates like this:`{% url 'school:new-school' %}`

Or remove namespace:

```
url(r'^school/', include('school.urls'))
```

to use url without namespace in template:`{% url 'new-school' %}`

Using [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) would be a bad approach in this case, since it's an instance method, designed to get url for single model instance.

If you want to add method to model, you should use something like this:

```
@classmethod
def get_create_url(cls):
    return reverse_lazy('school:new-school')
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I did as you stated. My project url was already as you stated, using namespace. I also left the get_absolute_url as it is and added the namespace as suggested by Geo. This did the trick.

Comment: get_absolute_url, as i described above, is designed to return url of sigle model. So something is wrong in your approach.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean now.